# Redux does not update state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with Redux, even more likely not a problem but a misunderstanding. 
If I do dispatch in a function and write a new value in the store then I can not immediately get into this function a new value from the store.

**Example:**

```
    testFunc = () => {
        console.log('in func: before', this.props.count);   //state store
        this.props.onButtonIncrementClick();                //dispatch a new state in the store
        console.log('in func: after', this.props.count);    //get the old state store
    };
```

**Live example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/yk1jzjv6l1

[image]

I suspect this is related to asynchrony since if I wrap the state in `setTimeout()` a new state comes.

I would be glad to hear an explanation of why and how you can write values ​​to the store and immediately read them from it.

Comment: "I would be glad to hear an explanation of why and how you can write values ​​to the store and immediately read them from it." Sounds like the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Generally you could use `componentDidUpdate` method to get new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`setState` is not synchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), whether it's you or Redux updating it.

This is a misunderstanding, as you say. When you're updating it directly you may supply a callback to be executed, e.g.,

```
setState({ foo }, () => somethingWith(this.state));
```

(Noting that the component has been re-rendered before the callback.)

If you have logic you need to run after an "external" state update (e.g., Redux) then there's `componentDidUpdate`, but it may also indicate an architectural issue.

Comment: I thought the component local state and redux global state are different things and when I use redux it does not intersect with the setState (component local state). I thought I was free of problems with asynchronous setState() using only redux to work with states.

Comment: I generalized--Redux is also not synchronous, e.g., state updates may be batched, re-ordered, and so on.